# WebException not caught in try/catch

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, try-catch, system.net.webexception

I saw several posts with similar problem but no solution works :/

I debug a windows service by using a console application. It executes tasks on website and must be able to collect http code status for create logs. As you can see, sensitive code is in try/catch.

When I debug (F5), I have a WebException that is not caught. When I run (CTRL + F5), the exception's message is write in my console and stops my program.
This is my code :

```
public partial class Schedulor : ServiceBase
{
void RunTasks()
    {
        schedulor.Start();
        List<Task> task = new List<Task>();
        foreach (TaskPlanner tp in listTp)
        {
            if (tp.CountDown == 0 && tp.IsRunning == false)
            {
                // Initialisation lors de GetTasks()
                tp.IsRunning = true;
                try
                {
                    task.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => tr = tp.ExecuteBot.Execute())); // WEBEXECPTION HERE (cannot find 404)
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {                        
                    if (e is WebException)
                    {
                        // treatment
                    }                       
                }                    
            }
        }
        Task.WaitAll(task.ToArray());
        CreateLogs();
    }
  }


 public class Bot : IBot
 {
 public TaskResult Execute()
    {
        TaskResult tr = new TaskResult();
        int codeResponse, timeout;
        string credentials;
        try
        {
            WebRequest wrSettings = WebRequest.Create(settings.Url);

            // treatment
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);                
            if (e is WebException)
            {
                var code = ((HttpWebResponse)((WebException)e).Response).StatusCode;
                if ((int)code != settings.HttpResponse)
                {
                    tr.MyResult = TaskResult.Result.nok;
                    goto next;
                }
                else tr.MyResult = TaskResult.Result.ok;
            }
        }            
    next:
        return tr;
    }
 }
```

I do not understand why my catch does not work. I need to treat this information because the task can test if a website return 404 or anything else.

Thanks in advance

EDIT : -----------

I reduce code as it requests because deleted code does not the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should catch that exception *in task*. Add another method, and create your tasks similar to:

```
task.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>  Process(tp)));

void Process(TaskPlanner tp)
{
    try
    {
        tp.ExecuteBot.Execute();
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    }
}
```